Spacetime point in forward light-cone
Consider the transformation of massless free scalar field $\phi$ under inversion of spacetime point, which is defined as,
$$I: x \to -\frac{x}{x^2}. \tag{3.2.27}$$
The two-point function of massless free scalar field in position space is,
\begin{align}
\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle &= \lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2 + i\varepsilon(x^0-y^0)}\\
%&= \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}+ O(\varepsilon)\right]
\end{align}
Now if we define the massless free scalar field transform in the following way,
$$I: \phi(x)\to \frac{1}{x^2}\phi\left(\frac{-x}{x^2}\right). \tag{3.2.29}$$
Then two-point function is invariant under this transformation, i.e.
\begin{align}
\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle &\to\frac{1}{x^2 y^2}\left\langle\phi\left(-\frac{x}{x^2}\right)\phi\left(-\frac{y}{y^2}\right)\right\rangle\\
&= \frac{1}{x^2 y^2}\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left[\frac{x^2 y^2}{(x-y)^2} + O(\varepsilon)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \frac{1}{(x-y)^2}
\end{align}
I am able to prove this one, but then it is stated on p.74 in chapter 3: "Dilatation" of "Aspect of symmetry" by Sidney Coleman that,

we still have to check the statement that the imaginary part of $x$ is in the forward light cone is invariant under the inversion.

Can someone explain, what does it mean?

Hi Aster Kleel. Just to check conventions, is the first 2-point function formula from a reference? Which page?

Hi @Qmechanic. after eq. 2.2.25 in chapter 3: "Dilatation" 0f "Aspect of symmetry" by sidney coleman , it stated that "The ambiguity in pole is removed by giving $x$ a small imaginary part lying in the forward light cone".
